# Flatter minimizer of a loss function tends to generalize better than sharp minimizer

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, optimization

I came cross this statement when reading paper https://openreview.net/pdf?id=H1oyRlYgg

The paper states that flatter minimizer can be described as low precision. My understanding is that if we think a function as a distribution; then flatter function indicates larger variance, hence lower precision. Hence, we need few bits to represent it implies better generalization.

I'm not sure if I can think this way when transform the loss function as probability distribution as these two not same.

Is there a better explanation to explain this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that the loss function of a model takes as inputs the parameters of the model and outputs the loss of the model when those parameters are used.

If the minima is sharp, this means that parameters *near* the optimal parameters have very different losses.  I.e. the loss is very sensitive to the perturbing of parameters.  Since you expect the parameters to be imperfectly estimated, due to your finite data set, this sensitivity is bad.

If the minima is *flat*, this means that the parameters *near* the optimal parameter have more-or-less the same loss.  I.e., the loss is *not very* sensitive to perturbing the parameters.  This is good.

Comment: So the badness of the sharp minima comes from the fact that because we use a finite training set to estimate them (and not the whole population) this estimation will change depending on the training samples and as such the final performance will be highly variant (assuming we average over all possible training sets of same size)? Of course, if we had access to the whole population we will blindly choose these parameters (corresponding to the sharp -possibly global- minima), but of course this is not possible.